# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-scroll-to-bottom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

I installed react-scroll-to-bottom and its showing in by dependencies but I keep getting this error:

Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-scroll-to-bottom'. 'c:/Users/J/Desktop/webapps/ChatApp/client/node_modules/react-scroll-to-bottom/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/react-scroll-to-bottom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-scroll-to-bottom';`

This is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "query-string": "^6.13.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-emoji": "^0.5.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-scroll-to-bottom": "^4.0.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

and here is my js code:

```
import React from 'react';

import ScrollToBottom from 'react-scroll-to-bottom';

import Message from './Message/Message'

import './Messages.css';




const Messages = ({ messages, name }) => (
    <ScrollToBottom classname="messages">
        {messages.map((message, i) => <div key={i}><Message message={message} name={name} /></div>)}
    </ScrollToBottom>
);

export default Messages;
```

Comment: check in your npm modules , `dependencies` and `devdependencies` are just a reference.

Comment: sorry am confused, what does that mean?

Comment: First, try to run `npm install`. If your issue is not fixed then delete the `node_modules` and `package.lock` files and run `npm install` again.

I know it's too late, but maybe it will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

so what I did was look for other means of achieving the scroll to bottom effect, and this what I used:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";


const Messages = ({ messages, name }) => {
    const messagesEndRef = useRef(null);
    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    };
    useEffect(scrollToBottom, [messages]);

    return (
        <div className="messages">
            {messages.map((message, i) => <div key={i}><Message message={message} name={name} /></div>)}
            <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had de same problem, with that tutorial from JsMastery
https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_chat_application

Initally i also though of it as a compiling error but is not such that problem.

The message you pointed is just a warning for internal composition of react-scroll-to-bottom, and it is not major error, it is related to typescript declarations.

It is solved by declaring the css class at the declaration

```
<ScrollToBottom/>
```

leave it this way:

```
<ScrollToBottom  className="messages">
```

then the scroll-to-bottom will begining to work

the warning is never disappearing.

the final code is below:

```
const Messages = ({ messages, name }) => (
    <ScrollToBottom  className="messages">
        {messages.map((message, i) =><div key={i}><Message message={message} name={name}/></div>)}
    </ScrollToBottom>
)
```

once the css declaration is set, the behavior is fixed

Comment: It is because the author does not take into account that matter until the second 1:42:12 approximately